# Text in a table cell should be wrapped only on hover and should just end with an ellipsis otherwise

Tags: html, css, html-table, word-wrap

**Requirement:**

I have a table in which some of the table cells might contain very long text (with no spaces at all or with spaces). Now , I don't want all the lengthy text to be displayed which only makes that specific column very long. Instead, I want the text in that cell to be something like 'sffasfashdsjfs...' if it exceeds certain length or the max width of that cell.

Only when I hover on that table cell, should I be displayed the text wrapped (even if text does not have white spaces).

**What I've tried using CSS:**

```
td
{
min-width:50px;
max-width: 300px;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}


td:hover
{
min-width:50px;
max-width :300px;
position:relative; // the cell adjusts its width to show the text
word-break: break-all; // for wrapping the text with no white spaces
}
```

**Result:**

The text does wrap when mouse hovers on that cell, but the problem is that this is not working in a uniform manner. Some table cells which do not exceed the max-width also assumes lesser width with text inside it wrapped and some table cells are not occupying the max-width.

I need all the cells to occupy their max-width first and then wrap later on hover and the cells whose text is less than max-width should remain unaffected.I also do not want the table layout to be fixed.

Need a CSS solution (not a javascript solution) for this.

Any workaround method for this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some HTML to go with that?

Answer (score 5):

The wrapping issue is a bit odd, it seems that changing the `td`s to `display: inline-block;` stops it from happening.

```css
table {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td:hover {
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet</td>
        <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit.Utcursusurnamassa,utaliquetodioconsecteturnec. </td>    
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut cursus urna massa, ut aliquet odio consectetur nec.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet</td>
        <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit.Utcursusurnamassa,utaliquetodioconsecteturnec. </td>    
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut cursus urna massa, ut aliquet odio consectetur nec.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the title attribute?

```
<table>
<tr><td>Some data</td><td title="Some really long data to show when the cell is hovered.">Some real...</td><td>Some more data</td></tr>
</table>
```